# crontab: same script is triggered only on one day

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi, scheduled-tasks, backup

I'm not a linux expert and need some support to a crontab mystery (for me).
I'd like to do a backup of my raspberry pi twice a week.
It's the same script. But only the every monday trigger (dow=1) executes.
The Friday rule (dow=5) does nothing at all - no backup saved.
I can't see why.
What's going wrong? Where can I find out what's going wrong?

```
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
0 4 * * 1 /home/pi/Backup/backup.sh > /dev/null
0 4 * * 5 /home/pi/Baclup/backup.sh > /dev/null
```

[screenshot of crontab -e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOTSl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did everything correctly. You were just missing a second pair of eyes to see that you have a typo in the second line:

`Baclup` vs `Backup`

;-)

Comment: Oh dear! Error 45 (Error sits 45 cm in front of the Display). Thank you very much for your peer review. :)